# Hide the border for cell in table using Aspose java

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

We have inserted the page numbers and footer text in the Footer using table but we want to hide the  cell border for the table.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094465/insert-page-number-with-text-in-footer-aspose-word-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply set line style of the cell borders to none:

```java
builder.getCellFormat().getBorders().setLineStyle(LineStyle.NONE);
```

In this case borders will not be visible.

Comment: code works thank you Alexey, Noskov. 
can help me how to align text to some extent to right side of the cell ?. Right now text inside aligned to completely left side

Comment: just specify paragraph alignment in the appropriate cell. You can do this using builder.getParagraphFormat().setAlignment() method. https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/paragraphformat#Alignment

Comment: yes we use setAlignment() to align Left, Right or Center but to align to some points away from cell, I used padding methods like setLeftPadding(), setRightPadding()